# Read Word128 from a bytestring

Tags: parsing, haskell, binary-data

As a haskell newbie i stuck with the problem: I have a binary data in bytestring and i want to convert it to the list of Word128's (assume that binary data is 16 byte aligned).
Actually I have troubles even to convert 16 byte bytestring to the Word128.

Anybody can help ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll write an instance for the binary parsing library of your choice. E.g. for [Data.Binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.5.1.0/doc/html/src/Data-Binary-Get.html#getWord64be), you'd write something like:

```
-- | Read a Word64 in big endian format
getWord64be :: Get Word64
getWord64be = do
    s <- readN 8 id
    return $! (fromIntegral (s `B.index` 0) `shiftl_w64` 56) .|.
              (fromIntegral (s `B.index` 1) `shiftl_w64` 48) .|.
              (fromIntegral (s `B.index` 2) `shiftl_w64` 40) .|.
              (fromIntegral (s `B.index` 3) `shiftl_w64` 32) .|.
              (fromIntegral (s `B.index` 4) `shiftl_w64` 24) .|.
              (fromIntegral (s `B.index` 5) `shiftl_w64` 16) .|.
              (fromIntegral (s `B.index` 6) `shiftl_w64`  8) .|.
              (fromIntegral (s `B.index` 7) )
{- INLINE getWord64be -}
```

that would then be glued into an instance Binary.

So, pick your binary parsing library (either binary or cereal), and write an instance for your type.

Comment: Where do we file a feature request for a `unsafeGetbe :: (Integral a, Bits a) => Int -> a` that would turn this into just `getWord64be = unsafeGetbe 8`? =)

Comment: Unrolled byte-level loops seem fine to me. Do you want to use TH to generate it?

Comment: I was thinking more like a `foldr (\byte val -> shiftl val 8 .|. fromIntegral byte)` or similar.

Comment: @Don is readN exposed outside the Data.Binary.Get ? or do you really suggest that he should modify the src for Data.Binary.Get?

Comment: @Jonke, @Don: it should be `getBytes` for both the binary (Data.Binary.Get) and cereal (Data.Serialize.Get) packages.

Comment: No, he should implement it in terms of the byte parsing functions that are exposed.